# How to convert React maps to React native flatlists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a **React** component that `maps` an array and renders a list of `VideoItem` components. I need the same behavior in **ReactNative** and I used the `FlatList` component to render the list but my ReactNative FlatList code doesn't work.
Here are my codes:

- React

  ```js
  import React from "react";
  import { View, Text, } from "react-native";
  import VideoItem from "../video_item/video_item";

  const VideoList = (props) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {props.videos.map((video) => (
            <VideoItem video={video} />
          ))}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  export default VideoList;
  ```
- ReactNative

  ```js
  import React from "react";
  import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
  import VideoItem from "../video_item/video_item";

  const VideoList = (props) => {
    const DATA = props.videos;
    const renderItem = ({ video }) => <VideoItem video={video} />;
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(video) => video.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  export default VideoList;
  ```

**Solution:**
I changed wrong `({ video }) => <VideoItem video={video} />` with `({ item }) => <VideoItem video={item} />` and the issue fixed.

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import VideoItem from "../video_item/video_item";

const VideoList = (props) => {
  const DATA = props.videos;
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => <VideoItem video={item} />;
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default VideoList;
```

Comment: what is the `props.videos` structure? is this an array of objects or array of strings or sth else?